# Find the volume of the region which lies inside $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ and $y^2 + z^2 = r^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Q: Find the volume of the region which lies inside $(1)\,x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ and $ (2)\, y^2 + z^2 = r^2$

My work so far:

I know for a fact that $x^2 + y^2 \geq 0$ and $y^2 + z^2 \geq 0$ but I am unsure how to use these inequalities for the solution.

Rearranging (2) gives me $z^2 = r^2 - y^2 \Rightarrow z = \pm \sqrt{r^2 - y^2}$ which also gives us the inequality $r^2 - y^2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow r^2 \geq y^2$ (but I'm unsure how to use this inequality either).

I know that the radius of the sphere is $r \geq 0$ and I know that $ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi $. I have a  feeling that my error is somewhere in this line.

I then set up my triple integral as:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{r}\int_{-\sqrt{r^2 - y^2}}^{\sqrt{r^2 - y^2}} dzdrd\theta$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

By "inside", I assume you mean the regions are $x^2 + y^2 \le z^2$ and
$y^2 + z^2 \le r^2$, where $r > 0$.  The first is a double cone with axis on the $z$ axis
and the second a cylinder with axis on the $x$ axis.

Consider the cross-section of your region at a certain value of $z$.  In order for there to be any intersection with the cylinder, we need $|z| \le r$.  The cross-section is then the intersection of the disk $x^2 + y^2 \le z^2$ with the strip 
$|y| \le \sqrt{r^2 - z^2}$.  Its area is then
$$ \int_{-|z|}^{|z|} 2 \sqrt{r^2 - y^2} \ dy$$
which you then want to integrate over $z$ from $-r$ to $+r$.